# Find and convert all ALAC files to mp3 / opus / aac

Tags: bash, find, ffmpeg

I'm looking for a way to convert all alac files in a directory recursively to another format.

Problem: alac as well as aac use suffix m4a, so `find -name "*.m4a"` doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me. Are you on the same directory as the files?

Comment: Well, it does find all m4a files, but not all m4a are alac. But I want to find alac files only. Not aac encoded m4a

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934936/determine-whether-an-audio-file-is-encoded-in-apple-lossless-alac

Comment: If you want to use ffmpeg, use ffmepg -v, ans find out to compile to `enable-nonfree`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a tool that can detect the codec in the m4a files. One such tool is avprobe which is available in debian based linuxes in package libav-tools (I use Ubuntu 14.04).

Then you can do like this (if there are no newlines in file names..):

```
find . -name \*.m4a | while read file; do avprobe "$file" 2>&1 |grep -q 'Audio: alac' && echo "$file"; done
```

obviously substituting `echo "$file"` for the convert command.

If it's not feasible to install such a tool, you can probably estimate it with `grep -q Halac "$file" && grep -q '$alac' "$file"`. The few apple lossless files I tested contain those two strings, but it can match files which are not really apple lossless codec with a small probability, and I'm not quite sure apple lossless files are guaranteed to contain those strings. If that's okay, the above becomes

```
find . -name \*.m4a | while read file; do grep -q Halac "$file" && grep -q '$alac' "$file" && echo "$file"; done
```